# How do I increment a global variable on a timer in processing?

Tags: java, global-variables, processing

I'm trying to increment a global variable every 5 seconds but I'm not quite sure how to do this. I've tried with a for loop within setup() and draw() however it doesn't seem to update the global variable and in turn the content linked to it.

```java
int count = 0;
int savedTime;
int totalTime = 5000;

void setup(){
    size(1280, 720); 
    smooth();
    savedTime = millis();
}

void draw(){
    int passedTime = millis() - savedTime;

    if(passedTime > totalTime){
        int x = 0;
        println("5seconds have passed!");
        count = x;
        ++x;
        background(#000000);
        savedTime = millis();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't tell you what you did wrong if you don't show your code.

Comment: sorry I've updated the post now cheers mate.

Comment: You do `x = 0` and then `count = x`, what did you expect `count` to be equal to ? Just do `count++`, you don't need `x`.